# CSS zoom vs. Javascript zoom battle

Tags: javascript, css, zooming

Looking at this example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSBdD/) (I'm using Chrome 33)

the CSS and Javascript set zoom on the same object are working in unison, and not like normal styles should be by overriding.. and in a selective manner.

CSS

```
#text { zoom: 0.8}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <div id='text'> text </div>
    <div id='other'> text fixed zoom 1</div>
</div>
```

^
an element with css zoom 0.8 looks at size 0.8. great.

```
var texty = document.getElementById('text');
texty.style.zoom = 1;
```

^
an element with css zoom 0.8 and a javascript (thus inline) zoom of 1 looks at size 1. great.

This I expect, the inline style set by javascript should have precedence.

```
texty.style.zoom = 0.8;
```

^
BUT an element with css zoom 0.8 and a javascript zoom of 0.8 looks size 1 as well. (0.8/0.8). Why now is it working together?

The fiddle linked toggles the javascript set zoom value from 0.8 to 1, but no visual difference is found demonstrating the above issue. I'd like to know why this is, and how to I work around it.

The purpose of this is so that a series of rendered html cards enter the page at a default 0.8, and as they are programmatically selected they "zoom" up to 1, then as passed they are "zoomed" back to 0.8 but this return breaks. It feels a waste to constantly scan the li's for new cards added to the list, hence I want a default zoom: 0.8 set via css.

Comment: checked in IE10 which behaves appropriately and as expected.

Comment: You mis-use `zoom` property. To scale contents, you should use CSS transform instead. See: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/

Comment: I can see your point. Not using the better standard is a form of mis-use... But webkit should not have implemented it broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `zoom` property in CSS standards, up to CSS3.

It is originally a proprietary CSS standards by IE, but later adopted by other browsers. It is theoretically working in all major browsers (Firefox has its own syntax, though), but it's proven not working well in Chrome 33, by OP. Another proof that it is NOT recommended to be used in production sites.

If you want to scale the contents, you can use [CSS transforms](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/).

p.s. If you change the text to an image, it works *sometimes* in Chrome.

It is suggested that you can use the followings for **images**:

```
#test img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; /* change from 100% to 80% for zoom: 0.8; effect */
}
```

For **texts**, you can just change the `font-size` (and for readability, you may want to change the `line-height` too).

Comment: Marked this as the best solution. "transform: scale()" works as it should and webkit has a broken implementation of "zoom".

changing the text to an image would not be nice though. Nor would having to re-style each content part (imgs and text) to make the same result. 

Scale is best, just need separate work for a way down to IE7 :(

Comment: If you find the answer useful, upvote it. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

I checked in newest chrome it is not working. 
I suspicious it is a bug.
But you can work around it by set it to a slightly different value. 
For example in your case you could set it to 0.79 and it will work.